# Facebook pixel tracking

Tags: facebook

We want to use Facebook pixels to track Facebook ads we post for certain shows.

Our site is a little different.  We have events under one site with 4 different store.

Should we post the pixel code just at check out?  Or on the events/band page?

Just unsure of where to place the code in magento to get the best results.

Thanks

Comment: What is the landing page for the ads? Do you have any params in the url? If so you can add this to you google analytics and see the whole path from the page to the cart.